# Enable Media Attachment by Remote URL in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, media, attachment

Is there any way to enable media attachment to accept remote URL in WordPress?

Normally in WordPress to be able to attach medias to the post, we need to upload it to local server first but here I want to be able just giving the URL from other site and have it as an attachment that we can search in media listing its name and use it in other post as normal attachment.

Any possible way?

Comment: belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Its already in WordPress!!!

When adding a new post, Click on the Upload media.

[image]

Now click the `From URL` section. Here you can attach image or video from external links.

[image]

Thats all. Cheers!!!

Comment: I know it but this one is suppose to add one by one into the post, it's not in the "Gallery" or if you browse it in "media" ~ we have only local media uploaded but I want remote link attachment available in Gallery tab. I think it does not come with WordPress, we need some hook but I don't know how.

Comment: Sorry. That option is not available by default.